# More Complex Syntax Highlighting for Python in PyCharm?

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pycharm, syntax-highlighting

[image: Python highlighting its too generic.]

I can't seem to find any resolution to this at all in PyCharm Pro. I have the following:

1. local variable
2. class name
3. class instance
4. class instance calling method
5. a global variable

But, everything is white no matter how vastly different the scope is.
Is there any way I can improve this with a plugin? Or, customize the Python syntax to be more complex?

I don't have any issue with this at all when customizing the JavaScript, HTML or many other languages syntax highlight color. It's just that with Python, the only thing I'm left with to customize is this:

[image: Editor, Color Scheme, Python]

How do I add more color to Python's Color Scheme in PyCharm?

Comment: I am just curious what color scheme are you using on your IDE in these pics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set those variables/classes/methods to any color in `Preferences` -> `Editor` -> `Color Scheme` -> `Language Defaults`, `Custom` and `Python`.

For more colors, you can even check the `semantic highlighting` in `Language Defaults`.

And of course, there are many color schemes available on github and other sites, which could be imported in `Color Scheme` tab.

Comment: @grundic Ah, perfect. Nice share :)

Comment: Is the highlighting different in IntelliJ? The Python color options are still very limited. I can't set a color for a name in class/method, or a field. self.name is white,  module.field is white, etc.

Comment: @EhsanKia Unfortunately, though the classes highlighting is inherited from `Language Defaults` -> `Classes`, which is almost the same in all jetbrains IDEs, python has some unique issues. You can see `Instance field` already has a foreground color there but not working. Related youtrack issues: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-8246 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26919 https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-26706